# What's the easiest way to "reply via DM" to a message in the Twitter web app?

Tags: twitter

When someone tweets with (for example) "please reply via DM", what's the easiest way of sending a direct message back to that user that links to that tweet?

The closest I can find is the option to share the tweet via DM in the share (outbox) menu, but you then have to select whom you want to share it with (and the originator isn't pre-selected) so it's obviously not intended to be a "reply" option.

There doesn't appear to be anything in the ellipsis menu either.

Answer (score 1):

When someone tweeting "please reply via DM", they can generate a link under that tweet. Clicking on that link with share the tweet also in DM with your message.[image]

<sup><sup>Image source:Google</sup></sup>

But if link is not generated then you have to with same way as you have mentioned by sharing your tweet to the person and start conversation.

Learn more [About Direct Messages](https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/direct-messages#basics).